# Some random temp cpp and exe file are created after execution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, terminal

I am new here and I don't know how this work, but I will try my best to explain my issue.

When I run my C++ code, it creates a file name stating with TEMP and it seems a copy of my actual code and I have already check my "TASK.JSON" and also setting and I couldn't find any solution to. I will link the issue with it and all the other snapshots and also a snapshot what it says when I execute it.

1. [Actual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0aY5.png)
2. [Result of Terminal after execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GewxZ.png)
3. [CPP and exe File and Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkZet.png)
4. [c_cpp_properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehWWt.png)
5. [launch Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VF95.png)
6. [setting Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkz47.png)
7. [task Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJt24.png)

These are the snapshot that I have. In the third picture you can see the thing I am talking about. Kindly tell me how to stop it from being created again and again.

I hope I have explained it good.

Thank You

I did search online and on YouTube and couldn't find any solution as I don't know what it is and why it come.

Comment: Please first try to reproduce this in a freshly setup "hello world" project. Then, don't link images of code here. You can copy'n'paste the code instead, see the formatting guidelines when editing. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I think you are using code-runner and not the tasks.json you have